# How to avoid taking me to the top of the page using anchors?

Tags: html, css, anchor

Is there any way to prevent me from clicking on an anchor to take me to the top of the page?

this is my code:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="slides">
<div id="slide-1">1</div>
<div id="slide-2">2</div>
<div id="slide-3">3</div>
<div id="slide-4">4</div>
<div id="slide-5">5</div>
</div>
<a href="#slide-1">1</a>
<a href="#slide-2">2</a>
<a href="#slide-3">3</a>
<a href="#slide-4">4</a>
<a href="#slide-5">5</a>
```

Comment: To the top of the page you're redirecting to? Seems like normal behavior. If link is on the same page `<a href='#idHere'>innerHTML</a>`. Otherwise `anchorElement.onclick = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }` in JavaScript.

Comment: no, this code is in the middle of the page

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use an anchor if I'm not trying to redirect. `text-decoration:underline;` in CSS to make it look like a link.

Comment: Clicking the (internal) anchor does not take you to the top of the page, unless it is just `#`. It takes you you to the element with that ID. If that element is at the top of the page, that is where the view port will scroll to. If the element is as the bottom of the page, that is where the view-port will scroll to. E.g : https://jsfiddle.net/8mb31wzd/

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the links?

Comment: the links move the div horizontally

Comment: The code you use to move the `divs` could add important context for this question. Please include it.  A [mcve] is always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A) If I understood you well, you can do it with pure CSS.

```
a[href*="#slide"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

B) After reading what you wrote in the comments, you can use what PHPglue suggested.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#slide"]')
.forEach($a => $a.onclick = e => {
   e.preventDefault() // don't go 
   console.log('but do your things')
})
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: but if I use this loses the anchor action

Comment: The anchor is to go to the reference and you said you don't want to. So, are you doing anything else with it?

Comment: the anchor does a horizontal displacement, but it must be kept in place

Answer (score 0):

As far i know you cannot avoid it its connected to the fact that when you get to page its need to be rendered.
Before that, this id just do not exist.

So no way to remove it.
You can only try to speed this up a bit. 
Just try to ensure that your page is loading fast.

Answer (score 0):

You have your syntax confused, but it's easy to understand how that happened... You can do internal page links that will allow you to jump from one spot (or section) to another inside the same page, or even to a specific paragraph inside another page. The problem with your sample code is that you are using HTML syntax to link to CSS.

```
<div id="slide-1">1</div>
...
<a href="#slide-1">1</a>
```

It's true that you use a `#` (hash tag) in your `<a>` tag. So, using `<a href="#slide-1">1</a>` should, theoretically, work. And yes, you can use an `id` of the same name to identify where the link should take you. However - you can not use the name for anything else on the page. It must be unique and specific to avoid any confusion. Since your `<div>` tag(s) have the same identifier as your anchor tags, and since you are using the CSS selector `id`, the browser is ignoring your `<div id=` statement because it cannot find the `#slide-1` style in your CSS file.
The easiest way to fix this is to change your code to:

```
<div id="css_style" name="slide-1">1</div>
...
<a href="#slide-1">1</a>
```

Doing so will allow the `<div>` to retain the intended styles and connect the link to the anchor on the page. Just don't give your CSS style the same name, use something else.
[W3C Links Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)